# Make YouTube to Count my "Autoplay" Clicks as Views

Tags: youtube, view, autoplay

So I have used java to load only a thumbnail of a youtube video. When the thumb is clicked, the image div is replaced completely with an embed of the video on "autoplay." Everything was working as I wanted BUT

[image]

On YouTube when I look at the Analytics/traffic sources the "Unknown — embedded player" views dropped 90%+ to almost nothing as seen on the picture at the above URL. This is apparently because "autoplay" views are not recognized by YouTube as legitimate views which i confirmed on stackoverflow and elsewhere.

So... I want the best of both worlds. **I want the fast load speed** that comes with loading only the thumb at first AND **I want to avoid autoplay so the views actually count** on YouTube when the thumb is clicked. My temporary solution is to set autoplay=0 which forces the user to essentially click the same thumb twice, though I would prefer to avoid the redundant  click.

[Here is a example page from my site that has 4 embedded videos.](http://www.tytyga.com/Delite-Blueberry-p/delite-blueberry-plant.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use waiting/loading image instead of video thumbnail. Then use jquery to replace that waiting image by youtube embeded code few seconds after page loaded.